# Set my own question as duplicate and closed, and now I want to change the duplicate target

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Recently I marked [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830017/multiple-implementations-of-an-interface-in-the-same-constructor-with-unity) as a duplicate. Later on I found another question with [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18471492) than the one I set as duplicate. Can I change the **This question already has an answer here** part for my question?

By the way, the OP of the second question did not accept an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not possible to change the duplicate target without reopening and closing it again. This *normally* requires 5 users to do so, but you could try to find a gold-badge holder in [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) (one of the question's tags) and ask him to do it on his own.

An alternative is to just edit your question and include the link. But it won't be as clearly visible then.

Comment: I can close my own questions as duplicates without any gold badges

Comment: @NuriTasdemir I'm not sure if that would work - you can only cast a close vote **once** for a single question (even if it is later reopened).

Comment: @NuriTasdemir for his own question, OP's vote is also binding. I cannot find where it is explained, but it works just the way it did with your question: someone suggests a duplicate and when you accept, it automatically gets closed through the Community User.

Comment: [status-completed] @nuri

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray - this also proves re-opening and closing (in that order) by a wielder of the dupehammer is possible.

Comment: Indeed, that is possible. I'm sure it's documented somewhere. I can even vote to re-open the question again, if I wanted, but then I could not vote to close again.

Comment: @CodyGray I guess this is because you can vote once for each situation: to close and to reopen.

Comment: Also note, a gold-tag user who closes as a duplicate can't reopen and close as a different duplicate.  This has bitten me a few times in the past when I've found a better duplicate after an initial dupe-close.  :(